# Can't read values of array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

```
const char reset = '3';
char savedArray[32] = "0000000000000000000000000000000";
savedArray[reset] = '1';
Serial.println(savedArray[reset]);
Serial.println(savedArray[3]);
Serial.println(savedArray);
```

So I am changing the value of the `savedArray` at position `3`, but when I read it out again I find it `0`.. What am I doing wrong? Why isn't reset the same as 3?

Serial output:

```
1
0
0000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: use saveArray[32] = {0}; instead of savedArray[32] = 0000000000000000000000000000000";

Comment: '3' is ASCII and is 48 + 3.

Comment: Why are you using `char reset` and not `int reset` ?

Comment: @MathewsMathai It should be `size_t reset`, if we wanted to nitpick.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo It's a genuine doubt (didn't mean to nitpick). My mentality probably differs a bit from yours. No offence! :)

Comment: @MathewsMathai No, it was *me* nitpicking :) `char` and `int` will work (because `3` fits), `size_t` would be the choice for generic indexing.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming ASCII or even EBCDIC encoding `'3'` is a value larger than 32. (In ASCII, it's 51).

The behaviour on using this in `savedArray[reset]` is *undefined* since you are attempting to access an index outside the *bounds* of the array `savedArray`. Use `const char reset = 3;` to assign the *numeric* value of 3 to any numeric type, *including* `const char`.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are changing the array element `51` (the value of `'3'` in the [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/)), so you are accessing outside of the bounds of the array.

Change to `const char reset = 3;`

Answer (score 2):

> *So I am changing the value of the `savedArray` at position `3`*.

Wait, there you went wrong. You're not at all changing the value at position `3`. In your code,

```
const char reset = '3';
```

is the same as

```
const char reset = 51;  //considering ASCII
```

because, character literal (*constant*)`'3'` represents decimal `51` (*in [ACSII](http://www.asciitable.com/)*) and for which , later

```
savedArray[reset] = '1';
```

is out of bound access, as `savedArray` is of size 32. You might want to write

```
 const char reset = 3;  //decimal 3
```

or,

```
#define RESET 3  //MACROS are better suited as "array index", just suggesting
```